# How can I disable multicasting and enable unicasting in ROS2

Tags: ros, ros2, dds

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am integrating ROS2 with another native DDS based application, both located on different laptops but in the same network.
My problem is that I cannot use multicasting due to certain limitations. So, I opted for unicasting for the discovery process.  I configured the native DDS based application as unicast as explained [here](https://community.rti.com/howto/configure-rti-connext-dds-not-use-multicast). But my ROS2 based machine still uses multicasting.
It is obvious that once I find the ROS2 based machine through unicasting, both discover each other and the communication works in both direction.
But how can i configure ROS2 to use unicasting ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/302092/how-can-i-disable-multicasting-and-enable-unicasting-in-ros2/) by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 667 on 2018-08-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are not many QoS settings made in the ROS2 RMW code; the Connext libs will look for a source of user QoS settings using the normal search order (detailed [here](https://community.rti.com/static/documentation/connext-dds/5.3.1/doc/manuals/connext_dds/html_files/RTI_ConnextDDS_CoreLibraries_UsersManual/index.htm#UsersManual/How_to_Load_XML_Specified_QoS_Settings.htm)) - meaning you can provide your own QoS settings to the Connext libs under ROS2, using a variety of methods. Here's what I did:

To disable multicast in ROS2, create a file named "NDDS_DISCOVERY_PEERS" in a directory from which your ROS2 application(s) will be launched (directory where the ros2 command is entered and run). Place in this file a list of the initial peers for discovery (make sure to exclude multicast and shmem) format as detailed [here](https://community.rti.com/static/documentation/connext-dds/5.3.1/doc/manuals/connext_dds/html_files/RTI_ConnextDDS_CoreLibraries_UsersManual/index.htm#UsersManual/NDDS_DISCOVERY_PEERS_File_Format.htm).
My file had: localhost,192.168.1.44
For other QoS settings, place in the same directory as above a "USER_QOS_PROFILES.xml" file containing the QoS settings you'd like to use in ROS2. These settings will affect the ROS2 applications launched from that directory.

this is the answer i received from a RTI colleague.

---

Originally posted by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) with karma: 667 on 2018-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [machinekoder](https://answers.ros.org/users/33820/machinekoder/) on 2019-08-26**:
That's a good answer. I just would like to add that this answer is Connext DDS specific. Changing this setting for eProsima fastrtps works different by creating a `DEFAULT_FASTRTPS_PROFILES.xml` with an `initialPeersList`.